# How to use tSQL to match and remove everything after a string?

Tags: t-sql

How can I use tSQL to find a string, and if it exists, return everything before that string?

i.e. in the example below, in an ETL process, how would we take the column from source, identify the string ?uniquecode= and therefore remove that, and everything else after it, in the SELECT statement for the sink column?

[image: Source Column to Sink Column, removing identified match and beyond]

How can I best modify this tSQL statement below to return the values in SinkPageURL column above?

```
SELECT SourcePageURL FROM ExampleTable
```

I have attempted a Fiddle here - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3b60a/4 using the below statement.  It is disregarding the values where '?uniquecode=' does not exist though, and also leaves the '?' symbol.  Need this to work with MS SQL Server '17.

Somewhat close, but no cigar.  Help appreciated!

```
SELECT LEFT(SourcePageURL, CHARINDEX('?uniquecode=', SourcePageURL)) FROM sql_test
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('?uniquecode=', SourcePageURL) > 0
         THEN SUBSTRING(SourcePageURL,
                        1,
                        CHARINDEX('?uniquecode=', SourcePageURL) - 1)
         ELSE SourcePageURL END AS new_source
FROM sql_test;
```

If you instead wanted to *update* the source URLs in your example using this logic, you could try the following:

```
UPDATE sql_test
SET SourcePageURL = SUBSTRING(SourcePageURL,
                        1,
                        CHARINDEX('?uniquecode=', SourcePageURL) - 1)
WHERE SourcePageURL LIKE '%?uniquecode=%';
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim Biegeleisen!  That works perfectly to get me the required values here :)

Comment: Hi Tim, would you know how to apply this statement to modify the existing data in the Sink column example?

Comment: Sorry Tim, on the UPDATE statement, I am getting this error below.

`Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.`

I've checked the data and it completely matches the above examples.  Have you any idea on the solution?

Comment: Hi Tim, I amended it to be the below, and it solved it!

`UPDATE sql_test
SET SourcePageURL = SUBSTRING(SourcePageURL,
                        1,
                        CHARINDEX('?uniquecode=', SourcePageURL + '?uniquecode=') - 1)
WHERE SourcePageURL LIKE '%?uniquecode=%';`

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen, I've came across an alternative of the _?uniquecode=_ format.  How could I introduce an OR rule to the SELECT statement please to *also* catch the following?

_/uniquecode=_

Comment: @PhilBarnes You may open a new question.  Stack Overflow is not an ongoing blog where you keep changing the question.

Comment: Apologies @TimBiegeleisen!  Have created it  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49108942/how-to-use-tsql-to-match-and-remove-everything-after-either-of-2-strings). Thanks again.