# How to use tSQL to match and remove everything after either of 2 strings?

Tags: t-sql

How can I use tSQL to find one of two strings, and if they exist, return everything before found string?

In an ETL process, how would we take the column from source, identify the strings **?uniquecode=** OR **/uniquecode=** and therefore remove those, and everything else after them, in the SELECT statement for the sink column? i.e. matching desired outcome below.

[image]

On [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49049547/how-to-use-tsql-to-match-and-remove-everything-after-a-string) I was provided with a solution that finds **?uniquecode=** successfully.  I just need to find a way to modify it to also look for **/uniquecode=**

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('?uniquecode=', SourcePageURL) > 0
     THEN SUBSTRING(SourcePageURL,
                    1,
                    CHARINDEX('?uniquecode=', SourcePageURL) - 1)
     ELSE SourcePageURL END AS new_source
FROM sql_test;
```

Comment: Hi Phil, I dropped an answer below.  As you can see, the query is fairly different than your first question, which is why it wouldn't work so well to just to give a new answer there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may modify your current query as follows:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN SourcePageURL LIKE '%?uniquecode=%'
         THEN SUBSTRING(SourcePageURL,
                        1,
                        CHARINDEX('?uniquecode=', SourcePageURL) - 1)
         WHEN SourcePageURL LIKE '%/uniquecode%'
         THEN SUBSTRING(SourcePageURL,
                        1,
                        CHARINDEX('uniquecode=', SourcePageURL) - 1)
         ELSE SourcePageURL END AS new_source
FROM sql_test;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen again, this works great, much appreciated!